# Call method by string?

Tags: php, oop

```
Class MyClass{
  private $data=array('action'=>'insert');
  public function insert(){
    echo 'called insert';
  }

  public function run(){
    $this->$this->data['action']();
  }
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
$this->$this->data['action']();
```

Is the only possibility to use `call_user_func();`?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->{$this->data['action']}();
```

Be sure to check if the action is allowed and it is callable

```php
<?php

$action = 'myAction';

// Always use an allow-list approach to check for validity
$allowedActions = [
    'myAction',
    'otherAction',
];

if (!in_array($action, $allowedActions, true)) {
    throw new Exception('Action is not allowed');
}

if (!is_callable([$this, $action])) {
    // Throw an exception or call some other action, e.g. $this->default()
    throw new Exception('Action is not callable');
}

// At this point we know it's an allowed action, and it is callable
$this->$action();
```

Comment: Be sure to check if the function exists: function_exists() first!

Comment: It works. Should I use any security tricks like function exists or functions allowed array ?

Comment: @MarekBar If input comes from user, you should always escape it properly.Ideally, use a white-list with allowed actions.

Comment: @JesseBunch you don't need to use function_exist if you allready check with is_callable

Comment: Worth mentioning that in some versions of PHP, is_callable doesn't respect visibility, [as commented in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.method-exists.php#65405)

Answer (score 17):

Reemphasizing what the OP mentioned, [`call_user_func()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) are also good options.  In particular, `call_user_func_array()` does a better job at passing parameters when the list of parameters might be different for each function.

```
call_user_func_array(
    array($this, $this->data['action']),
    $params
);
```