# Use variable when calling class method

Tags: php, oop

I can't seem to find an answer to this albeit I am probably not looking for the right thing being new to classes and oop. I would like to know if you can use a variable when calling a class method.

When a user logs into my system I wish to display them some chart on a dashboard based on their user role.

For starters here is an example of my class

```
class Dashboard
{
  function get_guest_graph1()
  {
    return 'guest graph';
  }

  function get_user_graph1()
  {
    return 'user graph';
  }
}
```

On the page I can echo say

```
$user->userRole;
```

This will return either guest or user.

So once I have established the role and put this into a varible ie

```
$role
```

Is there a way I can then do the following?

```
Dashboard::get_$role_graph1();
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451394/call-method-by-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but use with caution:

```
call_user_func(array("Dashboard", "get_" . $role . "_graph1"), $args);
```

Comment: can I ask why use with caution is this a bad thing to do? Thank you for your quick response, will mark as correct answer but have to wait 8 minutes.

Comment: There potential for abuse here. `call_user_func` may make your code unreadable. If your code is more like: `if ($bool) { op1(); } else { op2(); }` (ie. you know all the possibilities) just write it like that, don't use `call_user_func`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I will eventually have 7 user types, but I agree. The easier to read, the easier to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

While this question was already answered, I think there are far better ways to handle this, if readability is in question.

For starters, use camel casing on functions rather than chaining_characters_for_variable_names.

```
class Dashboard {
    function getFirstUserGraph() {
        return 'user graph 1';
    }
}
```

I would discourage using numbers in a function name!

Secondly, to accomplish your desire of calling Dashboard::getFirstUserGraph() simply make that a static function:

```
public static function getFirstUserGraph() {}
```

Then you don't have to instantiate the class but use it statically.

Lastly, to call a class method via a variable is rather simple without the ugliness of call_user_func(). See below:

```
$getGraph = "getFirstUserGraph";
Dashboard::$getGraph();
```

Works like a champ and looks a lot nicer. Hope that helps!