# passing class method's argument via ajax

Tags: php, jquery

A generic add record function in database.inc.php

```
public function insert($data, $table) {

        $columns = "";
        $values = "";

        foreach ($data as $column =>$value) {
            $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $columns .= $column;
            $values  .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $values  .= $value;
        }

        $sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";

        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        //return the ID of the user in the database.
        return mysql_insert_id();

    }
```

Method to Add category :

```
<?php
include './database.inc.php';

class Categories{
    public function AddCategory(){
        $db = new Database();
        $b->connect();
        $db->insert($data, $table);
    }
}
?>
```

In the insert method the $data is the $_POST array. This function is working fine but i want to pass the $_POST array not by php but by ajax jquery.
I will find out how to get post array in jquery but my question here is how will i make an ajax call to this specific insert method in categories class as there will be more methods in categories class like delete , update, etc etc... 
I've heard that in asp.net there is an option that they pass the page name as well as the method name in the URL: parameter of jquery ajax.

Updated:
This is how i am calling the method:
page : categories.php
class : categories.inc.php;

```
 <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            unset($_POST['submit']);
            $_POST['DateAdded'];
            $_POST['DateAdded']=date("Y-m-d");
            // print_r($_POST);
            $Connection = new Database();
            $Connection->Connect();
            $Category = new Categories();
            $Category->AddCategory($_POST,"categories");
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: How your `classes/methods` are routed ? how do you call them from `url`, do you have any mechanism for that ?

Comment: let me update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(functiopn(){
    $('form#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var postData = $(this).serialize();
        $.post('categories.php', postData, function(data){
            // the server response will be available in "data" variable
        });
    });
});
```

Here, `myForm` is used as an `id` of your form, so use this `id=myForm` in your form or if you have any, then use it instead of `myForm`.

**Update:** If you need to pass another argument then you can add another argument right after following line `var postData = $(this).serialize();`, like

```
var postData = $(this).serialize()+"&method=insert"; // or "&method=update"
```

Now, every form field (including `method`) is available in $_POST`array and you can access any`$_POST`variable just like you do in`php`from your`categories.php`file because the form has been submitted to this`script`.

Comment: this seems to be i was looking for but it will be great favour if u can explain how is it working.... please ... i have used $.ajax method but i dont see u are passing my insert() method name in $.post

Comment: @RameezShah, I didn't pass any `insert` method, is that a requirement ?

Comment: @RameezShah, you can just pass data from client/computer to server and i'm just posting the form to `categories.php` and rest of the work has to be done on the server and after you complete the `insert/update` the echoed/printed data will be back to your `$.post`'s anonymous function and returned data will be accesable from `data` variable.

Comment: @RameezShah, you are welcome and hope this is what you asked for :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a POST called "method" there you put "insert", "update", etc so in the php file you make a switch.

You need to send by ajax the method you are going to use? Ok, so send throw POST a param called method.

In php you should do something like this:

```
$method = $_POST['metod'];
if ($method == 'insert'){
    //execute insert
} else if ($method == 'update'){
    // execute update
} //... etc
```

Comment: how would ajax know what function i am referring to ?

Comment: Ajax doesn't need to understand... ajax just need to have the method name.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly discourage you to use this style of processing data. You are very vulnerable to SQL Injection. Take a look at these links:

[Wikipedia - SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

[SQL Injection Example](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

You can prevent this - if you know what you're doing - this by using the mysql_real_escape_string() function.

```
$safeData = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafeData);
```

Your JSON could be parsed by PHP's json_encode().

```
$jsonArray = json_encode($jsonString);
```

This function is very strict, do not make mistakes in your JSON code! For the AJAX async request, you should use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with the async key set to true. GET (url) parameters should be added behind the URL:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: "script.php?page=bla&method=blabla",
    type: "POST",
    data: { <object to be sent via JSON here> }
});
```

Comment: For the SQL injection part i agree acutally its on local host just for practicing i m learning OOP and ajax...

Comment: For the url: how would i do that...like i instantiated the class on categories.php. The class page is categories.inc.php and the insert methods in categories.inc.php is actually coming from database.inc.php

Comment: @RameezShah Hm, alright, but I'd recommend even when practicing to stick to safe coding style. You don't want to find yourself writing unsafe production code because you're used to doing it ;)

Comment: @RameezShah You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451394/call-method-by-string

Comment: @RameezShah I'm referring to the is_callable() function of PHP. It has some great benefits, also some safety issues when directly taking user input ;)

Comment: Whats that ?? Thats not related to my question bro..Simply i wanna know that is this possible to hit directly to a class method by ajax... like i have different methods in my categories.inc.php class but when i want the url some think like this :

url: categories.inc.php at addcategory()

Comment: @RameezShah You're trying to execute a method by sending an AJAX request? I'm quite sure you won't be able to do that directly. When you send the request, the PHP script will execute as normal, but with POST data. You're question is very vague though..

Comment: yes that is exactly i want... execute a php method with ajax....and the parameters in the php method be passed with jquery..