# Dynamically check for available method before running

Tags: php, validation, class

I am trying to reduce code on an API class, what I am looking to do is to make sure a method exists before calling the method inside of the class.

Will be passing a method as a variable need to see if that method exists inside of the class then run the method.

Sample code below:

```
<?php
    class Test {

    private $data;
    private $obj;

    public function __contruct($action,$postArray)
    {

        $this->data = $postArray;

        if (method_exists($this->obj, $action)) {
            //call method here
            //This is where it fails
            $this->$action;
        }else{
            die('Method does not exist');
        }

    }

    public function methodExists(){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}

//should run the method in the class
$test = new Test('methodExists',array('item'=>1,'blah'=>'agadgagadg'));

//should die()
$test2 = new  Test('methodNotExists',array('item'=>1,'blah'=>'agadgagadg'));
?>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change `$this->$action` to `$this->{$action}();` and it should work.

[More in depth answer here including call_user_func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451394/call-method-by-string)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the name of your constructor function and second, when calling the `method_exists()` function you should be passing `$this` as the first parameter, not `$this->obj`:

```
public function __construct($action,$postArray)
    {

        $this->data = $postArray;
        if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
            $this->{$action}();

        }else{
            die('Method does not exist');
        }
    }
```