# Why does a SimpleXML object evaluates to boolean TRUE?

Tags: php, simplexml

I am a newcomer to PHP and SimpleXMl.

I would not expect false under either of these tests.

```
  $xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<a><b>123</b></a>');
  var_dump($xml);
  echo $xml ? "true": "false";
```

or

```
  $xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<a><b></b></a>');
  var_dump($xml);
  echo $xml ? "true": "false";
```

however the second returns false even though an XMLSimpleElement object is returned.
I have the same issue with an xml doc with namespaces everywhere.

it means I cannot test for a failed XML parsing as
`if (!xml)` returns false

but `$xml->childen($namespace)` does not.

Please advise
TIA
Ephraim

Comment: Both snippets print true for me... what's your PHP version?

Comment: Which version of php do you use? With my php5.3.5/win32 it prints `true`.

Comment: The second one throws the following: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /t.php:2` here: http://codepad.org/KIbscPGh

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9kICdZ

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do PHP closures return in IF statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040067/what-do-php-closures-return-in-if-statements)

Comment: Am I right in thinking the edits to this question have changed the meaning? The OP originally posted the second block with an empty string and now it has become `<a><b></b></a>`?

Comment: @BrendanBullen - There was never an empty string. It remained invisible because code wasn't formatted as code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ah that makes sense! Viewing the source of the edits reveals that. Thanks

Comment: To clarify on the PHP version as it was commented different to the OP's observation the second example evaluating to true (instead of false): Either PHP 5.0 or PHP 5.1.0 / 5.1.1 was in use. [Edited answer with more details/references and a Schrödinger's Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050353/367456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue but I'll try to provide a couple of hints.

First, here's the rule when [converting objects to booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:
> [...] the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> [...] SimpleXML objects created from empty
>   tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

Second, the [SimpleXMLElement constructor](http://es.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) always returns an object but it can throw a warning and an exception.

So these are the possibilities:

```
// Casts as TRUE because it's an object
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<a><b>123</b></a>');
var_dump($xml, (bool)$xml);
unset($xml);

// Casts as FALSE because it's an SimpleXMLElement object for an empty tag
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<a />');
var_dump($xml, (bool)$xml);
unset($xml);

// Casts as FALSE because the $xml variable was never set sucessfully so it's not even set
try{
    $xml=new SimpleXMLElement('');
}catch(Exception $e){
}
var_dump($xml, (bool)$xml); // Notice: Undefined variable: xml
unset($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects in PHP (5+) evaluate to `TRUE`, *always*.

*One* exception are `SimpleXML` objects created from empty tags - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php :

> When converting to bool, the following values are considered **false**: [...] Internal objects that overload their casting behaviour to bool. For example: [SimpleXML](https://php.net/simplexml) objects created from empty elements without attributes.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<b></b>');
```

qualifies as such a `FALSE` `SimpleXML` object (`FALSE === (bool) $xml;`).

However

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('');
```

Throws an exception and will halt your program if not caught. If caught, `$xml` is not set.

### Why does a SimpleXML object evaluates to boolean TRUE (or more specifically to boolean FALSE)?

This is implementation defined. PHP extensions can tell what happens when an object is being cast. For example `(bool) $xml` for a boolean value (`false` or `true`) or `(string) $xml` for the string value and the `simplexml` extension has this implemented.

While a cast to `bool` is always possible, non-*stringable* objects fail with `string` casts. `SimpleXMLElement` has implemented casting to `bool` as well as `string` (and more primitive types like `int`):

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<b></b>');

var_dump((bool)$xml);    # bool(false)
var_dump((string)$xml);  # string(0) ""
```

Given your second example, [3v4l.org shows](https://3v4l.org/nZFt7) that PHP 5.0.0-5, 5.1.0-1 casts `new SimpleXMLElement('<a><b></b></a>')` to `bool(false)` and to `string(0) ""`. Later and more current PHP versions to `bool(true)` and to `string(0) ""`.

As you describe in the question, this second example *"returns `false`"*, which means `$xml` evaluates to false when tested non strict.

> however the second returns false even though an XMLSimpleElement object is returned.

This suggests your observation falls into the time of those older PHP versions before the implementation was changed for the specific case of the second example (c.f. [Bug #35028](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35028)).

On a more broader look, there seemed to be a time where empty objects actually evaluated to `false` by `ZEND_BOOL_NOT_SPEC_CV_HANDLER` via `convert_to_boolean` while they also evaluated to `true` by `ZEND_BOOL_SPEC_CV_HANDLER` via `i_zend_is_true` (c.f. [Bug #34199](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34199)).

This appears particularly interesting for this specific SimpleXML question as it may borderline a rationale why `new SimpleXMLElement('<empty/>')` evaluates to false.

So it was possible for any object to test for false (via `!`) having both structures aligned: `!((object)null)` and `!((array)null)`.

This is long ago and my understanding is that this stems from the times before Zend Engine 2 ([for PHP 5.3.0 Dimitry removed the `zend.ze1_compatibility_mode` setting](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0)):

> ```
> | Name                        | Def | Changeable  | Changelog                  |
> | =========================== | === | =========== | ========================== |
> | zend.ze1_compatibility_mode | "0" | PHP_INI_ALL | Available since PHP 5.0.0. |
> |                             |     |             | Removed in PHP 5.3.0       |
> ```
>
> Enable compatibility mode with Zend Engine 1 (PHP 4). It affects the cloning, casting (objects with no properties cast to **FALSE** or 0), and [comparing of objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20140711045319/http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php). In this mode, objects are passed by value instead of reference by default.
>
> See also the section titled [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5](https://web.archive.org/web/20140711045319/http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php). *([ref](https://web.archive.org/web/20140711045319/https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), [ref](https://web.archive.org/web/20100620222620/https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php))*

So very long ago, more current:

- conversion to boolean is done during evaluation
- it makes use of the cast to `bool` for `SimpleXMLElement`
- which is (as documented) `false` for empty XML elements

It remains the sole exception and it is useful to distinguish from the empty string `""` or the string `"0"` for node values.

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything that evaluates to true/false on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php (find "When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:")

Creating a SimpleXMLElement object will throw an exception if it fails. Following code should do what you need:

```
try
{
    $xml=new SimpleXMLElement('');
    var_dump($xml);
    echo 'true';
}
catch
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

To evaluate to true/false, you might be looking into ===, to explicitly evaluate to false.

```
$test = '';
echo $test ? 'true' : 'false'; // will output false
echo $test !== false ? 'true' : 'false'; // will output true
```