# Can I immediately evaluate an anonymous function?

Tags: php, anonymous-function, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Immediately executing anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568410/immediately-executing-anonymous-functions)

I want to immediately evaluate an anonymous function rather than it appearing as a Closure object in method args. Is this possible?

For example:

```
$obj = MyClass;
$obj->Foo(function(){return "bar";}); // passes a Closure into Foo()
$obj->Foo(function(){return "bar";}()); // passes the string "bar" into Foo()?
```

The 3rd line is illegal syntax -- is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to imagine why you would need to do this? Why not just assign result of the function to a variable and then pass that variable instead?

Comment: Also in these examples your function is pretty much just an anonymous function, does not have characteristics of a closure, it's not 'remembering' any variables from its current context

Comment: I realize that, I really didn't want to explain why I need to do this -- obviously it's an unusual situation.

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine, this sort of thing is done *all the time* in JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with `call_user_func` ... though that *might* be a bit silly when you could just assign it to a variable and subsequently invoke the variable.

`call_user_func(function(){ echo "bar"; });`

You might think that PHP 5.4 with it's dereferencing capabilities would make this possible. You'd be wrong, however (as of RC6, anyway).

Comment: Why do you consider it silly?

Comment: @Tadeck Well, it seems to me it doesn't make sense to perform an additional function call to `call_user_func` when you could just as easily do `$f = function() { echo '1'; }; $f();` Though there's nothing technically unsound about using `call_user_func` in this case, I find the explicit invocation more readable. I can see the appeal in the brevity of a single line with `call_user_func`, though.