# What does (function () { })();mean?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

What meens in JS write a code like this:

```
(function (window) { })(window);
```

or this:

```
(function () { })();
```

Comment: It's a duplicate so I voted to close, though I think the answers there aren't as good as the answers here. specially not [this wrong +17 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/592411/601179)

Comment: If someone looks for PHP 7, where this has been introduced.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568410/how-do-i-immediately-execute-an-anonymous-function-in-php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It creates a `closure`, a private scope hiding the variables from the `global object`

```
// Somewhere...
var x = 2;

...
...
// Your code
var x = "foo" // you override the x defined before.

alert(x); // "foo"
```

But when you use a closure:

```
var x = 2;
// Doesn't change the global x
(function (){ var x = "foo";})();

alert(x); // 2
```

Regarding to the syntax, it's just a self executed function, you declare it and then execute it.

Comment: TY! And when I pass a variable? Like this:
`(function (window) { })(window);`

Comment: @RigoReis. They become variables in the function. it's used for minifing code, nothing "real"

Comment: TY'll folks help me so much, special thanks to @gdoron

Comment: @RigoReis. No problem. Good luck in your new js way.

Answer (score 7):

It's a self invoking anonymous function or a function expression. It prevents you from creating variables in the global scope. It also calls the function right away.

```
function someFunc() {
    // creates a global variable
}

var someFunc = function () {
    // creates a global variable
}

(function(){
    // creates an anonymous function and 
    // runs it without assigning it to a global variable
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). It helps control the scope of variables since Javascript hoists variables to the top of their scope. They're also anonymous functions which execute or initialize immediately.