# php computing a variable on the fly using anonymous functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Sometimes while initializing variables, you want to pass them values that are too complex to be computed in a single command, so you usually either compute a dummy variable before and then pass its value, or define a function elsewhere, and pass it's return value to our variable.

My question (wish) is, is it possible instead compute to a variable on the fly using anonymous functions?

for example, instead of use this:

```
$post = get_post();
$id = $post->ID;

$array = array(
    'foo' => 'hi!',
    'bar' => $id
);
```

Lets  use something like this:

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => 'hi!',
    'bar' => (function(){
        $post = get_post();
        return $post->ID;
    })
);
```

Code is totaly random.

Comment: "Code is totaly random." a very unlikely combination of letters to come from any kind of random generation

Comment: @PeeHaa yes, it returns Closure::__set_state(array(
)) since closures are instances of the Closure class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the following would do just fine:

```
$array = array('foo'=>'hi!','bar'=>(get_post()->ID));
```

However, with consideration to your question being a bit more open ended and not specific to your code snippet, you may find this [stackoverflow answer acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568410/anonymous-functions-that-execute-immediately).

```
$a = array('foo' => call_user_func(
    function(){
        $b = 5;
        return $b;
    })
);
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: one side question: why you put $ before ID into (get_post()->$ID)? and the parenthesis are needed?

Comment: @Bakaburg my bad on the $ before the ID, i have updated the post with proper syntax. also the parens are most likely not needed, i just didn't test my code and was playing it safe :)

Comment: please consider memory leaks when using this type of notation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6657911/1481489 (although it has been fixed in 5.3.10) and also general memory overhead and speed: http://dboskovic.typepad.com/david-boskovic/2010/04/php-anonymous-function-benchmarks.html